# I need help configuring PulseAudio Equalizer default.pa

Tags: 14.04, pulseaudio, alsa, equalizer

Recently I faced an issue with `pulseaudio equalizer` on my PC with Ubuntu 14.04 the thing is that each and every reboot it puts `pcm` level to max `db` and the sound becomes distorted.

[image]

It does that when `EQ Enabled` and `Keep Settings` are ticked, if I untick `Keep Settings` after reboot my sound settings are saved. When `Keep Settings` are ticked it creates `default.pa` file at `/home/.config/pulse` this is how it looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/pulseaudio -nF
#
# This file is part of PulseAudio.
#
# PulseAudio is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# PulseAudio is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
# WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
# General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
# along with PulseAudio; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
# Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307 USA.

# This startup script is used only if PulseAudio is started per-user
# (i.e. not in system mode)

.nofail

### Load something into the sample cache
#load-sample-lazy x11-bell /usr/share/sounds/gtk-events/activate.wav
#load-sample-lazy pulse-hotplug /usr/share/sounds/startup3.wav
#load-sample-lazy pulse-coldplug /usr/share/sounds/startup3.wav
#load-sample-lazy pulse-access /usr/share/sounds/generic.wav

.fail

### Automatically restore the volume of streams and devices
load-module module-device-restore
load-module module-stream-restore restore_device=false
load-module module-card-restore

### Automatically augment property information from .desktop files
### stored in /usr/share/application
load-module module-augment-properties

### Should be after module-*-restore but before module-*-detect
load-module module-switch-on-port-available

### Load audio drivers statically
### (it's probably better to not load these drivers manually, but instead
### use module-udev-detect -- see below -- for doing this automatically)
#load-module module-alsa-sink
#load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0
#load-module module-oss device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input
#load-module module-oss-mmap device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input
#load-module module-null-sink
#load-module module-pipe-sink

### Automatically load driver modules depending on the hardware available
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
load-module module-udev-detect
.else
### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev support)
load-module module-detect
.endif

.ifexists module-android-audio-hal.so
load-module module-android-audio-hal
.endif

### Automatically connect sink and source if JACK server is present
.ifexists module-jackdbus-detect.so
.nofail
load-module module-jackdbus-detect channels=2
.fail
.endif

### Automatically load driver modules for Bluetooth hardware
.ifexists module-bluetooth-policy.so
load-module module-bluetooth-policy
.endif

.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
.endif

### Load several protocols
.ifexists module-esound-protocol-unix.so
load-module module-esound-protocol-unix
.endif
load-module module-native-protocol-unix

### Network access (may be configured with paprefs, so leave this commented
### here if you plan to use paprefs)
#load-module module-esound-protocol-tcp
#load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
#load-module module-zeroconf-publish

### Load the RTP receiver module (also configured via paprefs, see above)
#load-module module-rtp-recv

### Load the RTP sender module (also configured via paprefs, see above)
#load-module module-null-sink sink_name=rtp format=s16be channels=2 rate=44100 sink_properties="device.description='RTP Multicast Sink'"
#load-module module-rtp-send source=rtp.monitor

### Load additional modules from GConf settings. This can be configured with the paprefs tool.
### Please keep in mind that the modules configured by paprefs might conflict with manually
### loaded modules.
.ifexists module-gconf.so
.nofail
load-module module-gconf
.fail
.endif

### Automatically restore the default sink/source when changed by the user
### during runtime
### NOTE: This should be loaded as early as possible so that subsequent modules
### that look up the default sink/source get the right value
load-module module-default-device-restore

### Automatically move streams to the default sink if the sink they are
### connected to dies, similar for sources
load-module module-rescue-streams

### Make sure we always have a sink around, even if it is a null sink.
load-module module-always-sink

### Honour intended role device property
load-module module-intended-roles

### Automatically suspend sinks/sources that become idle for too long
load-module module-suspend-on-idle

### If autoexit on idle is enabled we want to make sure we only quit
### when no local session needs us anymore.
.ifexists module-console-kit.so
load-module module-console-kit
.endif
.ifexists module-systemd-login.so
load-module module-systemd-login
.endif

### Enable positioned event sounds
load-module module-position-event-sounds

### Cork music/video streams when a phone stream is active
#load-module module-role-cork

### Modules to allow autoloading of filters (such as echo cancellation)
### on demand. module-filter-heuristics tries to determine what filters
### make sense, and module-filter-apply does the heavy-lifting of
### loading modules and rerouting streams.
load-module module-filter-heuristics
load-module module-filter-apply

# X11 modules should not be started from default.pa so that one daemon
# can be shared by multiple sessions.

### Load X11 bell module
#load-module module-x11-bell sample=bell-windowing-system

### Register ourselves in the X11 session manager
#load-module module-x11-xsmp

### Publish connection data in the X11 root window
#.ifexists module-x11-publish.so
#.nofail
#load-module module-x11-publish
#.fail
#.endif

### Make some devices default
#set-default-sink output
#set-default-source input

### BEGIN: Equalized audio configuration
### Generated from: pulseaudio-equalizer
load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=ladspa_output.mbeq_1197.mbeq master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1e.2.analog-stereo plugin=mbeq_1197 label=mbeq control=-2.0,-2.0,-4.0,-0.0,0.0,-2.4,-4.8,1.5,0.0,1.1,3.0,3.0,5.8,7.8,7.8
set-default-sink ladspa_output.mbeq_1197.mbeq
set-sink-volume alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1e.2.analog-stereo 65536
set-sink-mute alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1e.2.analog-stereo 0
### END: Equalized audio configuration
```

I tried changing the line:

```
#load-module module-alsa-sink
```

to:

```
load-module module-alsa-sink control=PCM
```

(with starting # and without) still no luck, after:

```
killall pulseaudio

pulseaudio -k
```

the sound disappears or `pcm` back again to 100%

All I want is Equalizer to be activated by default each boot with my manual sound settings be kept. Is there anything else I could do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Finally, googling around for ideas and hints I figured it out how to optimize volume levels settings manually (e.g. `pcm`) I had to edit `alsa-mixer` configuration file for analog output:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common
```

there be:

```
[Element PCM]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right
```

and one has to change to:

```
[Element PCM]
switch = mute
volume = ignore
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right
```

also after `volume = ignore` you can manually set your prefered volume value for your ear adding a line e.g.:

```
volume-limit = 0.07
```

then in terminal run:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Done. The volume will be up to 100% but the `pcm` level will be left with your prefered value.

Also I received an email (reply) from **Launchpad** that describes a similar bug and advice to fix it:

```
sudo gedit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

and change:

```
flat-volumes = yes
```

to

```
flat-volumes = no
```

Though it mostly relates to Ubuntu 14.10 and later.